# What is this syntax is called?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What is the `_char` variable attached to the end of the `.each` method called?

```
variable.to_s.each_char do |char|
```

I am new to Ruby and I saw this for the first time and I don't know what its called (or what it does or how it works). Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

It is a different method named [`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_char), not a special syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Ruby there is no `String#each` method.  `String#each_char` is for enumerating characters of a string (though they are themselves strings). `String#chars` is the same as `String#each_char`.